# How to return any Object from retrofit asynchronously (can't call enqueue() method)

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I want to return `GetCheapestResponseType` object from Retrofit (asynchronously called) with RxJava:

This is my method:

```
public Single<GetCheapestResponseType> getCheapest(...) {

        ...

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(urlGetCheapest)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

        Controller controller = retrofit.create(Controller.class);

        Call<GetCheapestResponseType> callAsync = controller.getCheapest(...);

        callAsync.enqueue(new Callback<GetCheapestResponseType>() {
            @SneakyThrows
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetCheapestResponseType> call, Response<GetCheapestResponseType> response) {
                    ...
                    // return GetCheapestResponseType; ??
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetCheapestResponseType> call, Throwable throwable) {
                 //  return throwable; ??
            }
        });
    }
```

So I've made **GetCheapestCallbacks** interface:

```
public interface GetCheapestCallbacks {

    void onSuccess(@NonNull String result);

    void onError(@NonNull Throwable result);
}
```

I've added it as a parameter to `getCheapest(... ,  @Nullable GetCheapestCallbacks callbacks))` method

and `onResponse()` method I added:

```
calbacks.onSuccess(...);
```

and `onFailure()` method I added:

```
callbacks.onError(throwable);
```

In Controller interface I have:

```
public interface Controller {

    @GET("oneWayFares")
    public Single<GetCheapestResponseType> getCheapest(...);

}
```

I changed:

```
Call<GetCheapestResponseType> callAsync = controller.getCheapest(...);
```

For:

```
Single<GetCheapestResponseType> callAsync = controller.getCheapest(...);
```

And now I can't call `enqueue()` method on it.

How to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

Previously your return-type was `Call<>`. The Call class is the class which provides you with the `enqueue()` method to execute the api call. Since you now return `Single<>` it makes sense that `enqueue()` is not an option anymore.

I never worked much with RxJava ever since LiveData came out. But from what I remember, the API call is executed **as soon as you subsribe to the Single**. In other words: Only calling `getCheapest()` does nothing as long as you have no Subscriber attached to this `Single`

so something like this should work:

```
controller.getCheapest(...).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(
   // implement success and error methods
)
```

Edit: I can highly recomment to read "Reactive Programming on Android" by Christopher Arriola and Angus Huang. It is very well structured and helped me a lot to understand the concept of reactive frameworks.